# How to call a field on different models using qweb report in odoo 10?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have created a report using qweb , when i need to show the others data from different models it says error  "account.invoice object has no attribute 'pack_operation_product_ids'" . My main question here is how to call pack_operation_product_ids from that same module but different object or models. Thanks

**PP.xml**

```
<tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_product_ids" t-as="m">
<tr t-foreach="o.picking_ids" t-as="l">
<td> <span t-field="l.name"/> | <span t-field="m.name"/>  </td>
```

**models.py**

```
from odoo import fields,models,api

@api.multi

def get_data(self):
    record_collection = []
    # Do your browse, search, calculations, .. here and then return the data (which you can then use in the QWeb)
    record_collection = self.env['stock.picking'].search([('pack_operation_product_ids', '=', 'o.pack_operation_product_ids')])
    return record_collection
```

**return error**

```
AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'pack_operation_product_ids'

Error to render compiling AST

AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'pack_operation_product_ids'

Template: invoice_report2.qweb_inv_pp_document
Path: /templates/t/t/t/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr
Node: <tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_product_ids" t-as="m">

<!-- <tr t-foreach="request.env['stock.picking'].search([(

'pack_operation_product_ids', '=', o.pack_operation_product_ids.name)])" t-as="obj"> -->

<!--<tr t-set="record_collection" t-value="doc.get_data()">-->

<tr t-foreach="o.picking_ids" t-as="l">

<td> <span t-field="l.name"/> | <span t-field="m.name"/>  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing this code `<tr t-foreach="o.pack_operation_product_ids" t-as="m">` what you are actually doing is this, you are accessing `pack_operation_product_ids` field of object `o`, which is currently a recordset of `account.invoice` probably, as from your question. So, to need to access a particular field, you have to have that field defined on the model, `account.invoice`, you can just inherit this existing and add that field and related functions, but you didn't even inherited any model or create, just created a function which is wrong.

```
from odoo import fields,models,api

class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.invoice'

pack_operation_product_ids = field.One2many(compute='get_data')

@api.multi
def get_data(self):
    ...
    ...
```

your code don't have to be exactly like this, but something like this, based on your requirements which I don't know.

Also in your python code, you are using this term `'pack_operation_product_ids', '=', 'o.pack_operation_product_ids'` to search but the right leaf is a string and left leaf is a not existing field. I don't know how you think that is going to work.

Comment: Thanks you for help , but now i fix my code to this

<tr t-foreach="request.env['stock.picking'].search([('id', '=', o.picking_ids.ids)])" t-as="obj">

and its showing number of arays of field obj.pack_operation_product_ids